# Django using fields from two different models in another model

Tags: django, django-models

My models looks like following:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False) 
    pin = models.IntegerField(null=False, )
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.name)
class Localities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s, %s" % (self.name, self.city)

class Hall(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, verbose_name="Name of the Marriage Hall", )
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    landmarks = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, verbose_name="Landmarks of the Marriage Hall", )
    seating_capacity = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Seating capacity of the Marriage Hall",)
    ac = models.BooleanField(null=False, verbose_name="Is the Marriage Hall AC?",)
    garden_lounge = models.BooleanField(null=False, verbose_name="Is the Marriage Hall garden_lounge?",)
    avg_user_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, null=False, decimal_places=5, verbose_name="Average user rating of the Marriage Hall",)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, verbose_name="Customer comments for this Marriage Hall", )
    rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, blank=True, )
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s, %s" % (self.name, self.city)
```

This gives me browsable API as follows:
[image]

What I would like to have is also localities in my hall model, but when I select a specific city, localities related to that city should be populated.

How can I achieve this? How can I modify my models?

Comment: why do you need localities in the edit hall page? they are not (directly) related

Comment: Well I want them to be somehow related. The logic is like following: I select a city and then a locality in that city where my hall exists.

Answer (score 0):

I used 'django_smart_select' and it solved my problem.